# web scraping - stuck on printing the numbers

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape player's all stats.

I want these numbers to come out

```
Stats
2019 SEASON / CAREER
PPG
16.6 / 9.7
ASST
2.0 / .7
REB
6.5 / 5.9
FG%
61.5 / 59.9
FT%
64.3 / 47.7
3P%
17.6 / 66.7
```

## import libraries

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

## specify the url

```
url = "https://www.msn.com/en-us/sports/nba/montrezl-harrell/player/sp-id-30301000000698651"
result = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
```

## Take out the  of name and get its value

```
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "statsitem"})

print(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's dynamically loaded I think. Look to see if there is an xhr in the dev tools network tab that retrieves the data and you can mimic. Otherwise, to get layout as you show it, you can use selenium to automate browser which will allow the dynamic content to load then dump page_source into bs

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.msn.com/en-us/sports/nba/montrezl-harrell/player/sp-id-30301000000698651')
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')

title = soup.select_one('.playerstats h3')
print(title.text)
for item in soup.select('.statsitem'):
    print(item.select_one('.abbr').text, '\n', item.select_one('.statsvalue').text)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether you are familiar with selenium, python supports selenim. You can navigate to any url and scrape required data from dom.

You will get number tutorials from youtube and since your requirement is too straight forward, you can achieve this within no time using selenium.

https://youtu.be/GJjMjB3rkJM